# Why doesn't the default parameter being an empty array work with generic types?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts an argument that defaults to an empty array `[]`:

```js
function foo(arr: any[] = []) {
  return arr;
}
```

However if I use generics, there would be a type error:

```js
function foo<T extends any[]>(arr: T = []) { // ❌
  return arr;
}
```

```
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'never[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
```

Why does changing to generics cause a type error?

Comment: Because a caller could come along and call `foo<[string]>()[0].toUpperCase();` and the compiler should accept that because apparently your `foo()` function can return any array type the caller wants even if that caller doesn't pass in such an array.  Your default value `[]` is not assignable to every possible `T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you don't need an assertion in that case, `function foo<T>(arr: T[] = []) { return arr; }` is just fine because an empty array is always assignable to a value of type `T[]` no matter what `T` is.

Comment: does this explain what's going on to your satisfaction? Or is something missing?  I'm just trying to decide whether to write up an answer or whether there's more going on with the question.

Comment: @jcalz I am not sure I know what you mean by `foo<[string]>()[0].toUpperCase()`. "Your default value [] is not assignable to every possible T." but T is going to be `any[]`, it seems to be that `[]` is going to be assignable to a `any[]` no?

Comment: `T` is not going to "be" `any[]`, it's going to be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `any`.  `function foo<T extends any[]>(...` means that `T` can be any subtype of `any[]` that the caller wants.  For example, the one-tuple `[string]` is a subtype of `any[]`.  And while `[]` is assignable to `any[]`, it's not assignable to `[string]`.  Logically, `T extends any[]` and `[] extends any[]` does not imply `[] extends T`, no more than "A dog is a mammal" and "I am a mammal" implies "I am a dog".

Comment: In your generic function, I call `foo<[string]>()`, and the return type of that is going to be `[string]` according to its call signature.  And so I should be able to index into it with a `0` key and call its `toUpperCase()` method.  If I do that there will be a runtime error, precisely because you are using `[]` in a place that expects `T`, which will turn out to be `[string]` in this call.  Does this make sense yet or no?

Comment: @jcalz could you write up an answer please it is really hard for me to follow this way

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem as well, and the solution I came up with was to use overloads instead of a default argument value. That way, TypeScript knows to handle the case where the argument is absent differently from when the argument is present.

In your case, that might look like this:

```
function foo(): any[]
function foo<T extends any[]>(arr: T): T
function foo<T extends any[]>(arr?: T): T | any[] {
    if (!arr) {
        return [];
    } else {
        return arr;
    }
}

foo(); // <- Returns any[]
foo<string[]>(); // <- Not allowed
foo(['test']); // <- return type string[]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKAXIghmATwG0BdAKFElgWVQB4AVRAUwA8pmwATAZz0NIA+NLgBOonA2yIGFcNHhIUcRi3ade-YiWFjRAfknSmAHy2lEAbzIBIGMERoAhHoxXbN0cyghRSUgDctgC+LAA2PMzuNp7evkh6QTbBZCkUqJgBiAD02Yh0ALSIAEpxfnz42ukqPFCiMGAA5kKZOXmFiABycFB4YWFwAO7MXNVoRADkHLUTJBhZuflFXj5+iFAEAA5RtfVNpGRAA)

As @jcalz has explained in comments on your question, the issue stems from the fact that it's possible to explicitly specify a generic type when calling a generic function. For example:

```
function foo<T extends any[]>(arr: T = []) {
    return arr;
}

foo<string[]>();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBDMATwG0BdAPgApyAnVgLkSwF5F6AlIgDeAKACQrbFBCskbVgG5RAX1GiU6ElFYwwAc3rMByoA)

In the most obvious cases, like `string[]` above, this is fine because `[]` can be an array of any type. But there are other types that fit the `extends any[]` constraint which cannot be applied to `[]`. The example of a tuple that @jcalz used in their comments is an example of this:

```
function foo<T extends any[]>(arr: T = []) {
    return arr;
}

foo<[string]>();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBDMATwG0BdAPgApyAnVgLkSwF5F6AlIgDeAKACQrbFBCskbVgG5RAX1GiU6GiSisYYAOaMmA5UA)

In this case, your generic function should return a value of type `[string]`, but the value it returns is `[]` which is not of that type. Even though both `[string]` and `[]` both match the `extends any[]` constraint.

That's why the overload solution I've presented makes the function only generic if the argument is present, so the generic type can always be inferred from that argument. Instead of using an optional argument, the default value is set within the function.

---

In the specific example used in this question, the simplified generic function with no constraints suggested by @jcalz in a comment will work fine:

```
function foo<T>(arr: T[] = []) { return arr; }
```

However, there are more complex cases where the overload method I've suggested can be more useful. Here is a simplified example of one place where I've used it, where the utility of using overloads came with maintaining an inferred string union type and passing it through to the return value.

Sorry for the complexity of this example. It's a small piece from a more complex library that I'm part way through rebuilding, and I've struggled to isolate and simplify it much further than this.

The important part is that the overloaded function returns a generic type, and that type needs to be inferred correctly whether an argument was passed or not. In this case, the inferred type is a string union, which can be very useful for autocomplete particularly when it includes many strings.

```
/**
 * A function for summarising a set of numbers
 */
type Summariser<T = any, G = any> = (numbers: number[], groupName: G) => T;

/**
 * A group of Summariser functions
 */
type Summarisers<SummaryName extends string> = Record<SummaryName, Summariser>;

type DefaultSummaryName = 'Count';
const defaultSummarisers: Summarisers<DefaultSummaryName> = {
    Count: (numbers: number[]) => numbers.length
} as const;

/**
 * A 2D array of the results of Summariser functions applied to an Group of numbers,
 * able to be printed to the console using `console.table`.
 *
 * The header row starts with "Value", then lists the names of each summary.
 * Subsequent rows list the name of the set of numbers, then list each of its summaries.
 */
type Summary<SummaryName extends string> = [['Value', ...SummaryName[]], ...[string, ...any[]][]];

/**
 * Create a 2D summary array that can be printed using console.table.
 */
function summarise(numMap: Map<string, number[]>): Summary<DefaultSummaryName>
function summarise<SummaryName extends string>(numMap: Map<string, number[]>, summarisers: Summarisers<SummaryName>): Summary<SummaryName>
function summarise<SummaryName extends string>(numMap: Map<string, number[]>, summarisersArg?: Summarisers<SummaryName>): Summary<DefaultSummaryName> | Summary<SummaryName> {
    // If there was no argument, use a default value instead. This will affect the return type, as per the overloads
    const summarisers = summarisersArg ?? defaultSummarisers;

    const summaryNames = Object.keys(summarisers) as DefaultSummaryName[] | SummaryName[];
    const summaryHeaderRow = ['Value', ...summaryNames] as const;

    let summaryValuenumbers: [string, ...any[]][] = [];
    for (let [groupName, numbers] of numMap.entries()) {
        const summaryRow: [string, ...any[]] = [groupName];

        for (let [, summariser] of Object.entries<Summariser>(summarisers)) {
            const numbersSummary = summariser(numbers, groupName);
            summaryRow.push(numbersSummary);
        }

        summaryValuenumbers.push(summaryRow);
    }

    const summary = [summaryHeaderRow, ...summaryValuenumbers];

    // Let the overloads tell TypeScript which type the summary actually is.
    // If there was no `summarisersArg` argument, it will be Summary<DefaultSummaryNames>,
    // otherwise the type T could be inferred so no default was necessary and it will be Summary<SummaryName>
    return summary as Summary<DefaultSummaryName> | Summary<SummaryName>;
}

//////////

const exampleGroup = new Map([
    ['Row 1', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
    ['Row 2', [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]],
    ['Row 3', [0, 2, 4, 8]],
]);

console.log(exampleGroup);

const exampleSummary1 = summarise(exampleGroup); // <- Correctly inferred type as Summary<"Count">
// console.table doesn't work in the TypeScript Playground, so use console.log instead
console.log(exampleSummary1);

const summarisers = {
    sum: (numbers: number[]) => {
        if (numbers.every((el): el is number => typeof el === 'number')) {
            return numbers.reduce((sum, el) => sum + el, 0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
const exampleSummary2 = summarise(exampleGroup, summarisers); // <- Correctly inferred type as Summary<"sum">
console.log(exampleSummary2);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhBSBmBXAdgYwC4EsD2LE4BOkAzkgLbkCGhWJWKA5pFaQKYaQ4KQoUBGbQiSghg4DAE8ADm0gBlCtVokhAHgAqkALwsUkgDSQA4jr2SAfGYAUfcoOEAuXgKEBtALpHGhHEmkAclTkbM7GAJQ6VhoA3ODgoBDQcJA+ftJcPIqUNHRCiKiYuCgi0OJSsgpKuarCatnKkkEhkGwAHhhsKAAmJKQYtExWugBKbGhE3fXVhE3BbEYNNUIWcRIycgAibAhUSAA2GEuzzXK6AOQAwn4oGOdxEyWc3Tt7h8d5TlU5KkIkattdgcjjM5iFhpAAN7gACQ11QGGctlcXzsDk8kW0VjRfwAdPsuowMAALcAAXxYfUeJAwa0SohSACZNixCIQqJJMpASXJCGwyIc+txvspPgV0Ng8H0qNJpPssGxutycHoTL5-FyccIDAyqPwCcrIIJINJBp0lRgVTzINScAakPQmJAAAa2gm4jB6gnO3GiBkaYlyQNUF7EXwAd36NAwfXDWBJkAARAA1Kj7JBsRNGHn4eU0vrWlDzIU8NhUNDE0ig33JRT8VQARwzt0gEb6ec4hfmXOtqk4wq1JGzgdzdE4ZYrXPjfTIPwVJBrYnWlWOkmmPzBcnanR6M4GDEYELcbnOqfTbHORlx19Xp08Xkg19xbhpg0YV+vVH09-vdLADMuPkqE6FhIGZKsN1ZdlORJYCbS-I05FNBhzUgB0DxtKU7TYD0vRw0RxGQCVigg0VVGRcgAFkZWcajpDUV8DyMLVPAscJnFXAFXmBW95gscAiKKPBSOWddGlOVoOi6Xp+jfCwKLo2iZQY-cmGYlFWKMWcyL+DiZk+f5ePBdiRRoNcjLYfjBMlfBtNEizJJ3GTGKGBSaMgOiVLfdT7HcDwLC0-TahIWBCEYAB+PS52CsSzNONiosaLigXeUF4sgAAfUzZlik4+KhKBICK4BgEgABJHgeT5SBwyoPoUBVGhGAoLoMCMB05FYF4Us4AA3NMM0gBgaTLbpcUgAM6BqrB9n2FgEAQcZO0DVsOCQQh8AqBZKRNfJrRwXqhH2HAQ1KIrMKeETfmEMw7OukKwsgcLwsgbq3hBaK-jWc6LppK7Nz6XQAHl+AAKyW3EAGs2EkEhrDugzIjqyBAXeizPEy7LN08OIfupTg7skAAJUahBGHBI10E8zwzS9H2vQnThIDwdvx77zoJAnQRproURIZwX1U996dxL9JB-FmqY8XHzoQIhIGsTnIDcNJ-FOHyHGZzUKDo3FWtoflrHCSJoR+vGpS5jdyfDAWXOFp8xfvMwVfVQJ5ml+Izdl+XFY4ZXAs+wgWeFEHwcwPXbgNwygpWeGY+EY2Cq9r38ZcXzhFXW744ozXvFd05whl5PzsJ63cWkB1iRzv5V0LwqvbJT3k8JnnB3Lyu46tim65+xv69+y3GmdwmSZDMmKY-XEW4G3n0+Z9nitKgAZP39sOwhjtO7k2FmiaNnkNBaGkThw2JLBJy27kVsJlhMCQNN9k5Oga3OkrysqwNqtq+qVWdBHgtCowZ0rJmohFuEYeM01d7Gk4qjHiaViwBX7m-HAVU4yqCvnIS+WgJgHCVMaBgi02SKlICqBqr1uKHBqsjFA4x+QkDMnoJUkC4zQLkJxCy-Efp8gwOtWyoIdqwMoR9cS+UsocIQeCOIfcSqyLkeIcAqd2jBDlGwYwrszC0MjHRawbh+4nmtpAAAjHTNwRijCMiMAAZiMAAFiMAAVg8F4fR5xDGMlMQANiMAAdiMAADiMAATiMAABmcTqH6BiKaQCsaY0JFi7EBIieADwddFFYXdMdRg1hlHkFUeo9I6SlFtBUQSVcRis6fVyaU-JBJCn+ELpAN+agAC0kBrjEMwI-IaKAiF8gtBsQRoI1CJnhLcRM-E35uhwp6fUchug4H5Cgc4J8iCQ16ZgvesgD5H04AABX2ByVWPQtIqg6r9bC+IcDMGGp0EMGSShXOyTUspbAKnFItldAyZhTYlwoEiQczgWJpKiEnZOWAeDV2EHrdekhrC5P2CZHeQ16oojBVtYUKLtA4sgOcLU5xE5-OLkVHhfC06a1xAMpAaA2AItnEYHemIrCzkgAAalaPsMJPdk4Uh3hg4lJKyUbRcLNIuZtG693JA8L5eTVGrkZFUnSry6lqNdgHHSCcYjNNKm0jpRA+TdKfn0oQAzuRDORpxRMs5JmPJIM8m5Kr5WgkZHXIAA)

Comment: wow thanks for the answer! I finally understood it! but I wonder if there is a way to achieve this by just using conditionals without function overloads? because my understanding is that in TypeScript function overloads are all replaceable by conditionals

Comment: Hi Mark I just created a conditional version https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgIYBOBAXIhogKYAeUFYAJgM6J5gCeA2gLqID8ZiUuHoVgMMBXqIAvIm4BKUuWq0GzVpx79ypDd0SIA3gCgDBghSggCSQgQDcxgL7HjEBIygsZyVDnmO7mCeiABGPihwOBwA5HgxXAFuHl4QEX4ciACMiY6uQA and it _almost_ worked except there is a type error "Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends any[] ? T : undefined'"

Comment: also I wonder is your function overload solution any different than @jcalz's solution `function foo<T>(arr: T[] = []) { return arr; }`?

Comment: @jcalz's simple function there does the same thing with less code in this specific case, but I've also found the sort of overload solution I've suggested here have been useful in more complex cases where I wanted to use a generic function with a default value for an argument, but where that sort of simplification hasn't been an option.

Comment: I see two type errors in your conditional version there. One is that you're attempting to return a value of type `T extends any[] ? T : undefined` but your function's return type is `T extends any[] ? T : any[]`, so if `T extends any[]` is not true then you're telling your function that it should return `any[]` but it is returning something that should be `undefined`. I don't know what's going on with that other error about `never[]` though.

Comment: "more complex cases where I wanted to use a generic function with a default value for an argument" could you give me an example of this?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my answer to include one

Comment: thanks... so do you think function overloads are not always replaceable by conditioanls?

Comment: I don't know, but even if they are I certainly think that there are times when overloads are preferable. I find they're just easier to follow, personally.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was trying to reproduce the unsafetyness that @jcalz pointed out with my original approach. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAFQKYGcoB5mNQDylTABN1EwQBbAI1QCcA+ACgEN76AuFAbQF1EAXkT8AlIgDeAKESJ6qKCHpJ29AHRVWAB2YwiVIY0R7UBgFSIATKKkBfKVIgJMiVkJQYozHgEYANJZ8Ng6gkLAIHpiWOHiExGQU1HT0-Cyq3LjCYpIysnnyisquHBrauvqGxhUW1nYOTmAuNO5oUVg8lLQMfCziAPR9iV0pfH7GjUSsJIhwwCKdyXwOQA could you take a look at it to see if you know why `Test2<[number]>` doesn't give us a `[number]` type, instead it gives use `number[]` type?

Comment: Hover over `map`, you'll see it's become `Array<number>map<number>`. Must be due to how TypeScript has typed `Array.prototype.map`.